# Issue with JSON data encoded from the server, not able to plot the chart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am getting correct array of JSON objects from the server and assigning that to series.
chart_cfd.series also shows correct object in the debugger but chart plotting is not happening.

What could be the issue here? Do i need to change type of array members?

Note: If i provide series data locally in javascript, chart populates perfectly( simple column type)

Javascript:( I am using highcharts framework)

//series = [] in chart object

```
function requestCFDStatusData(){

  $.post(
     'ajax/cfdUtil/cfd_status.php',

 function(response){
                       chart_cfd.series = response;
                       });
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$cfdData = array(
    array(
'name' => 'A',
'data' => array(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,22,34,23,11)),
    array(
'name' => 'B',
'data' => array(83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3,22,50,34,11)),
    array(
'name' => 'C',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,100,25,45,42)),
    array(
'name' => 'D',
'data' => array(42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1,32,33,46,54)),
    array(
'name' => 'E',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50)),
    array(
'name' => 'F',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50)),
    array(
'name' => 'G',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50)),
    array(
'name' => 'H',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50)),
    array(
'name' => 'I',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50)),
    array(
'name' => 'J',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50)),
    array(
'name' => 'K',
'data' => array(48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50))

);

$jsonEncoded = json_encode($cfdData);

echo $jsonEncoded;
?>
```

Note: Following data works fine if i provide locally in javascript

```
series: [{
            name: 'A',
   data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,22,34,23,11]

        }, {
            name: 'B',
   data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3,22,50,34,11]

        }, {
            name: 'C',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,100,25,45,42]

        }, {
            name: 'D',
   data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1,32,33,46,54]

        },{
            name: 'E',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        },{
            name: 'F',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        },{
            name: 'G',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        },{
            name: 'H',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        },{
            name: 'I',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        },{
            name: 'J',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        },{
            name: 'K',
   data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,12,12,44,50]

        }]
```

Comment: what is your issue??because your question saying that every thing works correct and fine...

Comment: Chart plotting is not happening, updated thanks

Answer (score 2):

use content-type as javascript in header

```
   header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

and then use getJSON method of jquery as

```
      $.getJSON('ajax/cfdUtil/cfd_status.php',function(response){
          chart_cfd.series = response;
                   });
```

Comment: I guess i have some issue with JSON string conversion in PHP as i am using non associative array :(

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use `application/json` in your `php` file or you can use `text/plain` and then you can use `$.parseJSON`

```
function requestCFDStatusData(){
    $.post('ajax/cfdUtil/cfd_status.php', function(response){
        chart_cfd.series = $.parseJSON(response);
    });
}
```

[**This may help you**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file).

Comment: response is already a JSON object as i am setting header for JSON in PHP